# Who are these characters in the end of the last episode's still?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

The two similar looking guys on the left are most probably Ginkaku and Kinkaku Ebisugawa brothers, and the tiger must be Yaichiro. But who are the three female characters? They don't look like any of the other characters in this show. Is this perhaps a reference to another P.A. Works show or its crew?

[image]
(click the image for full scale)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Going counter clockwise from the top left:

- Kinkaku (upper, older brother)
- Ginkaku (lower, younger brother)
- Suzuki Satomi (Benten, as a schoolgirl she wears the blue blazer and has [her hair up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enbOc.jpg))
- Yaichiro (tiger ver.)
- The Mom (of the four Shimogamo brothers, house mother ver.)
- Yasaburo ([cross-dress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU5P4.jpg) ver.)

Kouji Kumeta, best known for the *Sayonara, Zetsubou-Sensei* manga, did the original character design for the series.

Comment: That's what I first thought - Kumeta's style is very recognizable in this one!